# Kubernetes Storage for multinode on VPS

Tags: docker, vps, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes setup ( Did from some tutorials) basic setup on 4 VPS servers 1 Master node and 3 worker nodes. But now I have read up on Persistence volume and I don't know from where to start.

The plan is : To host a website that has continuous uploads, but I need to get the data across all workers to be shared what is the best option for cluster-based is there some Kubernetes module or addon that I can use so that all 3 workers share the data and if one let's say days the rest continues to work? Please help as I need to all the data including MySQL are scaled on all 3 worker nodes and if one worker node goes down all work is continued with worker nodes 1 and 2 until the 3 restores or gets replaced.

Please point me in the right direction as I cannot create an NFS server on the VPS.

Answer (score 0):

1. CNS

Sticking with Kubernetes, the obvious answer would be to look into Container Native Storage solutions (eg: Ceph and Rook, or GlusterFS which I wouldn't recommend).

Though this usually implies sizing your nodes and attaching block devices accordingly. In some cases, dedicated nodes could make sense, avoiding concurrency issues. Otherwise make sure Pods all have cpu/memory requests and limits properly set.

A simpler solution could have involved something like MinIO. Setting this up isn't much complicated, could easily rely on your hosts filesystem. Though the main issue would be that your applications have to implement s3 storage. No MySQL database. Unlikely your site could work that way.

2. Dedicated Cluster

Another take on it would be to deploy your own storage cluster, on separate nodes. Ceph being a good candidate, look for ceph-ansible playbooks on GitHub.

Here, using small nodes (1-2 CPU, 4-8G RAM, 1-3x 1T SATA2, 1x1G network) would be easier than with Rook. Even though performances won't be amazing, it will be reliable nevertheless. Hardware recommendations aim at best performance, Ceph was meant to run on commodity hardware.

3. Dedicated Host(s)

Simpler than a storage cluster: something like a pair of FreeBSD, using ctld (iscsi target), hastd (devices sync in between your hosts), carp (VIP) and ifstated (scripting hastd sync failover based on VIP state). And probably ZFS, for volumes management, snaphots, ...

Or a pair of Linux with tgt (iscsi target) drdb (devices sync) and keepalived (VIP + scripts). And LVM volumes/snapshots.

Or just a single server (not recommended).

Maybe stick to NFS shares (not recommended).

4. Third-Party

With a little luck, your hosting provider does offer with a solution (iSCSI, ceph or gluster block devices, maybe some NFS share, ... avoid samba ones). Could be expensive, in some cases.

5. None of the Above

Otherwise, you're left with hostPath volumes.

Data would be written directly on a given Kubernetes nodes, you would have to map Pods with persisting data with a static node.